# my webview isnt appearing in my android app but there is no error

Tags: android, webview, assets

In my android app im trying to open a webpage the app is running but the webpage isnt opening, its appearing a a blank space.

I have attached the html and resource file in the assets
[java file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEBMX.png)

Comment: Should be file:/// and not file;///

Comment: I corrected that, but still I am getting on my emulator screen - Web page not available.The web page at file:///android_asset/facebook2.html could not be loaded because : nett:ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: file:///android_asset/Facebook2.html - you have capitalised the filename, otherwise change your filename to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

fb_url have a semicolon instead of  a colon. it should be

```
file:///android_asset/facebook2.html
```

not

```
file;///android_asset/facebook2.html
```

Comment: I corrected that, but still I am getting on my emulator screen - Web page not available.The web page at file:///android_asset/facebook2.html could not be loaded because : nett:ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND